# Apple Photos isn't allowing merging two of the same pets

Tags: photos, macos

Apple Photos is automatically finding the faces of my pets and tagging them as the same pet.  However, on 4 of my pets I've found that it creates duplicate "Pets" for them and it's not providing me the option to merge the two. I do see that option if I select one of those pets and a totally different pet, but not these two duplicate Pets.

One thought I had is that this may be related to Apple sometimes thinking that "both" pets are in the same photo even though there is only one. However, perhaps more importantly, I also noticed that when right clicking when both are selected compared to when I choose one with another pet it seems to think that one of these is a "Person" and one is a "Pet".

Any way to fix this?

---

In this screenshot, I've selected two of the pets that are the same, I right clicked and do not see an option to merge these pets.
[image: In this screenshot, I've selected two of the pets that are the same, I right clicked and do not see an option to merge these pets.]

---

In this screenshot, I've selected one of the pets from the previous example along with a totally different pet and here when I right click I do see the option to merge these pets.
[image: In this screenshot, I've selected one of the pets from the previous example along with a totally different pet and here when I right click I do see the option to merge these pets.]

---

In this screenshot, I've selected the other of the duplicate pets and then the totally different pet and am also missing the merge option.
[image: In this screenshot, I've selected the other of the duplicate pets and then the totally different pet and am also missing the merge option.]

Comment: I can select "this is not <pet's name>" for the person, then again give it the right pet's name and choose the pop-up of the pet (that's not a person) to unite the two, since I cannot merge people and pets.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is enabled (or bug fixed) on iOS 17.2.1 for my iPhone.

Before that build, this was a bug (or a feature they intentionally were not allowing yet).